# Average result line in plot

Tags: plot, netlogo

In my model I have set a plot, i did it, at the end of the whole run of the model in this plot has to be average horizontal line for my trades which took place among my agents (sellers and buyers). How have I to write in plot pen?

```
plot count patches with [count turtles-here = 2]
```

is that right command for average value?

Comment: unable to make head or tail of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want an "average line" to appear in your plot, just add another plot pen and give it the average value. how this average is computed cannot be easily assessed from your description. if it is the fact that buyers and sellers are always at the same patch, then your above code computes the absolute number of trades (assuming that everyone is trading). if you want an average, you have to remember each of in a list, e.g.:

```
globals [
  trades
]

to setup
  ... 
  set trades []
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ...
  let trades-in-this-tick count patches with [count turtles-here = 2]
  set trades lput trades-in-this-tick trades
  tick
end
```

and then use the following for the "average" plot pen:

```
plot mean trades
```

Comment: thank you for your contribution, i did how you write it but i became this error

MEAN expected input to be a list but got the number 0 instead.
error while observer running MEAN
  called by plot 'Trade Prices' pen 'pen-2' update code
  called by procedure SETUP
  called by Button 'SetUp'